# permission denial for content provider when called from within the same app

Tags: android, security, android-contentprovider

I have only one app. It has a content provider that is **not exported** (I don't want other apps to have access to the content) I have successfully been using the content provider until now.

I have created a content observer to update a **TextView**. The `onChange` method gets called when the content changes and it tries to re-query that content. That's when it gets the security exception that looks like this:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading org.sil.lcroffline.data.DataProvider uri content://org.sil.lcroffline/users/by_account_name/5555544444 from pid=0, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Here's the code that generates it:

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = mContentResolver.query(UserEntry.buildUserPhoneUri(mAccount.name), null, null, null, null);
        // do stuff with the data in the cursor
    } finally {
        if (c != null) c.close();
    }
}
```

The URI looks like it's formed properly, and I don't think there's a problem with matching it in the content provider.

The code above works fine when called programatically from within the app, it's only when it's triggered by a change in the observed data that the Exception occurs.

How could I get a permission denial from within the same app, and how do I fix this?

Behold the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.sil.lcroffline">

    <!-- To communicate with LCR -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Required because we're manually creating a new account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".authentication.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ReportActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <service android:name=".authentication.AuthenticatorService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <provider
            android:authorities="@string/data_authority"
            android:name=".data.DataProvider"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".data.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your android OS is 6.0?

Comment: Can you try exporting the content provider URI?

Comment: Yes it's 6.0.1, and no I don't want to export any part of the content provider. All the content should not be accessible by any other app.

Comment: @have you get runtime permission?

Comment: IMO, android stores all content provider data globally i.e. out of your app's private memory so you'll need to ask for a permission to access (read/modify) your own data.

Comment: look here for runtime permission demo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: good idea @pskink I've added the manifest to my post.

Comment: no it's just in a normal fragment

Comment: but it's the SyncService that changes the data that triggers the ContentObserver.onChange in the fragment, that gets the exception.

Comment: When I register the content observer I also call it's `onChange` method manually to fetch the current data, and that time it works fine.

Comment: I just added that info to the question - the exception only occurs when `onChange` is triggered by a change in the data

Comment: Thanks guys, solved it now. Sorry I hadn't given you the right information to see where the problem was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out this is caused by me not using a `Handler` in the `ContentObserver`

When you don't pass a handler to the content observer the `onChange` method gets called directly instead of a message to call it being posted through the handler. This is all well and good, except that the process that calls the `onChange` method in that situation is the System OS, which doesn't have the necessary permissions to query my content provider.

To fixed this I changed the code where my content observer is created from this:

```
mUserObserver = new ContentObserver(null) {
    // override onChange methods here
}
```

To this:

```
mUserObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
    // override onChange methods here
}
```

I was clued in by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694212/getting-a-permission-denial-when-querying-my-own-contentprovider-from-my-own-app)